# Zend2 Module can't be initialized

Tags: zend-framework, module

Here my Module.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonModule for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2012 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

namespace Users;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;

class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
            // if we're in a namespace deeper than one level we need to fix the \ in the path
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function onBootstrap($e)
    {
        // You may not need to do this if you're doing it elsewhere in your
        // application
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    }
}
```

And here my module.config.php:

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Users\Controller\Index' => 'Users\Controller\IndexController',
        ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'users' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    // Change this to something specific to your module
                    'route'    => '/users',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        // Change this value to reflect the namespace in which
                        // the controllers for your module are found
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Users\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    // This route is a sane default when developing a module;
                    // as you solidify the routes for your module, however,
                    // you may want to remove it and replace it with more
                    // specific routes.
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'users' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

But when I try to see the index page I get this:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught
>   Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException: Module (Users) could
>   not be initialized. in
>   /var/www/html/communicationapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php
>   on line 195
>        ( ! ) Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException: Module (Users) could not be initialized. in /var/www/html/communicationapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php
>   on line 195

Anyone knows what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check:

1. The filename is `Module.php` - that exact case.
2. That `Module.php` is in `module/Users` (i.e. not in `module/Users/src/`)

Comment: Yeah the filename is Module.php,  and it's in module/Users. Anyway I missed I added this to my composer.json: 
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Application\\": "module/Application/src/",
            "Users\\": "module/Users/src/"
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I used internal server of php where I don't have xdebug enabled it got this:

127.0.0.1:48908 [500]: /public/ - Uncaught Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Config being merged must be an array, implement the Traversable interface, or be an instance of Zend\Config\Config. boolean given. in /var/www/html/communicationapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ConfigListener.php:342
Stack trace:

## 0 /var/www/html/communicationapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ConfigListener.php(127): Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ConfigListener->addConfig('Users', false)

## 1 [internal function]: Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ConfigListener->onLoadModule(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))

## 2 /var/www/html/communicationapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))

## 3 /var/www/html/communicationapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('loadModule in /var/www/html/communicationapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ConfigListener.php on line 342